# How to perform 30k sequential API calls (node) [ERROR: connect ECONNRESET]

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous, post, get

My problem is that I have to extract data from a CSV file, make a GET request to a MySQL database (through loopback) and depending on the answer either do a Post request or not update an instance.

The import of the CSV file works fine, when I start to loop over it and make API calls all the GET reuqests are made after each other, without resolving any of them.

The performance is not an issues, since it is an importer that has to run only once. So I guess the behaviour I'm thinking of is a queue:

1. The entries from the CSV are in an array of objects
2. Take one object at a time
3. Make a GET request
4. Wait for the response
5. Make a Post request
6. Wait for the response
7. Take the next object from the array

Is this the easiest way to go? If so how to implement this sequential behaviour?

I'm new to backend development, so this is quite confusing to me.

Here is my code:

### Edit

I'm using axios now, however I still receive the error:

`ERROR: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:1338`

The error shows up when there is to many parallel get requests. How can I get around this?

```
const createSan = () => {

    const data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'test_mid.csv'), { encoding: 'utf8' });

    var options = {
        delimiter: ';', // optional
        quote: '"' // optional
    };

    const json = csvjson.toObject(data, options);

    json.forEach(item => {

    

        if (item['BDBNR'].length > 0) {

            let sanNr;
            let sanPartOne;
            let sanPartTwo;
            let sanPartThree;

            if (item['BDB_SORTENTEXT_NR'].length === 5) {
                sanPartOne = (item['BDB_SORTENTEXT_NR']);
            } else {
                failedCount++;
                return new Error('BDB_SORTENTEXT_NR incorrect');
            }
            if (item['SAN_MITTE'].length === 12) {
                sanPartTwo = item['SAN_MITTE'];
            } else if (item['SAN_MITTE'].length === 0) {
                sanPartTwo = '000000000000';
            } else {
                failedCount++;
                return new Error('SAN_Mitte incorrent');
            }
            if (item['SAN_ENDE'].length === 12) {
                sanPartThree = item['SAN_ENDE'];
            } else if (item['SAN_ENDE'].length !== 12) {
                sanPartThree = item['SAN_ENDE'];
                for (let i = sanPartThree.length; i < 12; i++) {
                    sanPartThree = '0'.concat(sanPartThree);
                }
            }

            sanNr = sanPartOne + sanPartTwo + sanPartThree;


            if (sanNr.length !== 29) {
                failedCount++;
                return new Error('SAN Nummer incorrect');
            }


            const getData = async () => {
                try {
                    const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:1338/api/articles?filter={"where":{"bdbnr":"${item['BDBNR']}"}}`)
                    postCall(res.data);
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            }

            getData();

            const postCall = data => {
                if (data.totalRowCount > 0 && data.rows[0]) {


                    if (data.rows[0].bdbnr.length > 0) {
                        data.rows[0].bdbnr = sanNr;
                        data.rows[0].tstamp = 1;
                        data.rows[0].crdate = 1;
                        data = data.rows[0];

                        const postData = async() => {
                            try {
                                console.log('fired')
                                const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:1338/api/articles/${data.id}/replace`, data)
                                 .then(res => {
                                     console.log(`Status: ${res.status}`);
                                     console.log('Body: ', res.data);
                            })
                        } catch(err) {
                                console.log(err)
                            }
                        }

                        postData();
                    }
                }
            }


        }


    })

}

createSan();
```

Help is deeply appreaciated

Comment: You cannot load the whole file at once. Take a look at streams (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50487888/4480179). Also, imports should be at the top of the file, don't put require('http') in the `map` loop

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Sorry maybe I didn't make it clear, the import of the CSV works fine, the problem are the API calls (it runs all the GET requests after each other, without resolving any). Can the stream of the CSV file help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Start using `async` `await` in for loop and you will get queue of downloading files one by one. As for downloading itself - use Axios for convenience as its promise based and could be easly used for such tasks.